# Getting issue while loading image in push-notification Service :Unable to resolve host : No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, security, amazon-s3, server, push-notification

We are getting images in the notification payload.

In notification payload we got AWS s3 URL like this:

**https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/images/users/ce4f4bdf-3458-4fac-8faa-1334cf4bfce3/ce4f4bdf-3458-4fac-8faa-1334cf4bfce3.thb.jpg**

But sometimes it is giving issue while setting to notification UI like

**java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host: No address associated with hostname**

This got resolved by changing the mobile internet network.

But this issue is faced by our actual users also.

Is there any solution from code for this?

Comment: We're you able to find any solution? We are experiencing the same. We send notification to 180,000 users, but about 4,000 have a problem downloading the image `java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "tca.b-cdn.net")`.

Comment: For us, 2-3 million users are affected by this.

Comment: Try using a cloudfront CDN url hosting as well, hard to say what the issue could be, but there could be DNS filtering applied on client networks, directly by ISPs as well